unable to login via putty ssh to my ec2 linux instance in aws : no supported authentication methods available
i am new in aws,
i created two linux instances : amazon linux and ubuntu linux
I downloaded RSA  ppk key pairs + imported to putty, however I am unable to login via putty,
i get this error
no supported authentication methods available;

when I logged via web console to amazon  linux, i wass surpised that there is no auth.log

so I checked on ubuntu and I found this logs:


Apr  3 06:19:36 ip sshd[11329]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Apr  3 06:19:38 ip sshd[11329]: Connection closed by authenticating user ubuntu port 4798 [preauth]

Any idea

I suggest you closely follow a beginners tutorial. It's not difficult but there's a few things to do such as making sure your security group allows logins from your IP, converting your key, using ec2user@ip or ubuntu@ip, etc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/connect-linux-inst-ssh.html is one tutorial, the first I found, there are probably a thousand similar tutorials online so find a recent one you like.

"I downloaded RSA ppk key pairs" - WTF? You GENERATE key pairs and use ssh-copy-id to deploy the public key where you want to access (using password authentication for the initial transfer),

I feel like a few of these comments are misleading, but Tim seems to be closer. Based on the log info, is seems like you ARE making it to the server. ssh-rsa seems to be depreciated and disabled by default for security reasons. Check out this Stack Exchange question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721606/ssh-server-gives-userauth-pubkey-key-type-ssh-rsa-not-in-pubkeyacceptedalgorit Are you using an older version of Putty? I'd start there before enabling ssh-rsa.

It looks like you are making a connection with the server, but trying to use ssh-rsa which appears to be depreciated and disabled by default for security reasons.
If you have not updated Putty in a while, start there. Newer versions support other, more secure, options.
Another option is to re-enable ssh-rsa, but due to the security concerns, that may not be a great idea.
There is nearly an identical question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721606/ssh-server-gives-userauth-pubkey-key-type-ssh-rsa-not-in-pubkeyacceptedalgorit
